# Android - read a C structure into android

Tags: android, data-structures, struct

I have a C structure with 2 attributes, say the content and the val
How do I read this into an android file? Does android support any structure?

My structure is like

```
struct data[] = {
    {"aakash", 2260},
    {"anuj", 1}}
```

How to read such structures in android?

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw I dont know much about JNI ? Can you please elaborate on how can i read C structure in android?

Comment: This will help you. Please let me know any other issues.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771366/reading-a-simple-text-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android supports Java Platform. Structure is not belong to Java. You Can Achieve the Same with Pojo Classes.

```
Public Class MyData {

    private String username;
    private double points;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public double getPoints() {
            return points;
    }
    public void setPoints(double points) {
        this.points = points;
    }
    public MyData(String username,double points)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.points = points; 
    }
}


MyData[] data = new MyData[2];

data[0]= new MyData("aakash", 2260);
data[1]= new MyData("anuj", 1);
```

Comment: My database is very large..i cannot use classes for it...isn't it?

Comment: Here there are two Fields, so you can go ahead with Pojo classes, as I explained. How come Database is related in this context.

Comment: I have my data in a file, so how to I read the file... The file is in the from "aakash" 12 \n "anuj" 6 \n and so on

Comment: InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.toc); // or you can use AssestManager to open File like this /* AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("test.txt"); */                                 
     System.out.println(inputStream);
     ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

     int i;
  try {
   i = inputStream.read();
   while (i != -1)
      {
       byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
       i = inputStream.read();
      }
      inputStream.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is as simple as a String and an Integer, and you really wanna write to file using C, read using Java. You can use a Plain Text File, Use a CSV format to store the values. It'll be easy to read/write in both languages.

You can't store those objects into a binary file and have Java read it effortlessly. Although, If the file was created using Java, then it should be easy.