# Java Apache FTP Server crashing

Tags: java, android, apache, ftp

I want to create a simple FTP Server in Android. I tried some libs (SimpleFTP, SwiFTP, ..) but I want to use the Apache FTPServer.

I read [Apache Ftp server integration with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934143/apache-ftp-server-integration-with-android) and [writing a java ftp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969097/writing-a-java-ftp-server) but the problem I have is that my phone crashes at the first line:

```
FtpServerFactory serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();
```

How can I solve that?

I have set the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Android Version:

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post the logcat please?

Comment: Ok, it says "Could not find class 'org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerFactory' (...)"

Comment: I've added these Libs:
mina-core-2.0.4.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.2.jar
ftplet-api-1.0.6.jar
ftpserver-core-1.0.6.jar

Why can't it find this??

Comment: The libraries are in the folder "Referenced Libraries"..

Comment: With other libraries, it's working, so it's very strange..

Comment: Now, I got this error: "Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/ftpserver/ftplet/FtpException" What's wrong today??

Comment: **Can anybody help please??**

Answer (score 1):

Remove Build path and select all libraries in libs then right click -> Build Path -> build these jars. Done. (simply remove build and renew build).