# Choosing from a list which will display the contents of a file(from a list of 100+ text files)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments

I am writing a little application but I am stuck.

It's an application which will list, open and display song lyrics. The lyrics are saved in a .txt file and are named: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.... 600.

**Here are the basic functionalities:**

- Display a list of songs by title.
- When the user click on the title it will open and display the file in an activity or fragment.

Here is an idea of what it might look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG3pw.jpg

Here are my main challenges:

How to grab the title for all the files? ( they are in the first line of each file).
what's the best way to store the files. In a SQL database, XML ?

Thank you for any tips you might give me. As long as I can get this working, I am good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start using Google a little bit:

The first result for "Java reading text file Android" is -> [Reading a simple text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771366/reading-a-simple-text-file)

And yes, you probably want to store that in a SQL Database.

But you need to do some more research and start with basic tasks first. This question is too broad and contains too many sub-questions.

Comment: Thank so very much, I will keep that in mind. At least now I have a starting point.

Comment: Sure thing, don't hesitate to post more specific questions, like: I am trying to read this file and I get this error. here's the error, here's the code. ;)