# I want read file in Android Project

Tags: android, file

I want read file in Android Project. But my code is not working. Can you help?

```
            String dosyaAdi = "sozluk.txt";
        String satir;
        try{
            BufferedReader oku = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dosyaAdi));
            satir = oku.readLine();
            while (satir != null) {
                tvDeneme.setText(satir);
                satir = oku.readLine();
            }
            oku.close();
        }
        catch (IOException iox){
            System.out.println(dosyaAdi+" adli dosya okunamiyor.");
        }
```

Comment: Where is `sozluk.txt` located? You have it in your `res/` folder?

Comment: src/com/sozluk.txt . MainActivity.java next

Comment: You should place the text file inside assets folder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771366/reading-a-simple-text-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `sozluk.txt` to `<your project dir>\assets\sozluk.txt`, and access it with:

```
BufferedReader oku = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(dosyaAdi)));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are putting the code inside the mainActivity, (change the code accordingly to the activity

```
try
        {
            MainActivity.context = getApplicationContext();
            AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
            InputStream instream = am.open("sozluk.txt");
            if (instream != null)
            {
                InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream); 
                BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader); 
                String line,line1 = "";
                try
                {
                    while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null){
                        line1+=line;
                        Log.e("File Read", line.toString());
                    }
                }catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Exception Occurred", "Exception Occurred"+e.getMessage());
                }
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Danial code is absolutely right but after Android 6.0 (API level 23) they have introduced run time permission. Place your read file code in below success block.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{

  private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION = 786;

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {            
        readFile();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    requestPermission();
  }

  private void requestPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION);
    } else {
        readFile();
    }
  }
}
```