# trying to have a text file as part of my app, so my app can load it

Tags: android

I am using android studio to build my app.  I have a text file called testdata.txt.  I would like this file to be loaded in with my app.  Then have my app read the file.  I figured out how to open and read files, but I dont know how to add the file to my project so it will be loaded when the app is loaded.

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771366/reading-a-simple-text-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the file in `/res/raw`

Then you can access it through:

`getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename);`