# FileInputStream and FileOutputStream

Tags: java, android

I created a `.txt` file and want to save the data I type into a textbox into the file. And if I click on a button I want to load the data I saved out of the file. I have the code for both, but it does not work, I hope you can help me if I have some mistakes :)

Load out of file:

```
public void Liste() throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        FileInputStream instream = openFileInput(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                + "/assets/bmiwerte.txt");
        if (instream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
            String line, line1 = "";
            try {
                while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null)
                    line1 += line;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String error = "Fehlermeldung!!!";
        error = e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Save into file:

```
public void SaveList(View view) {
    //Pfad, im privaten Speicherbereich Environment.getDataDirectory();
    File file = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/assets/bmiwerte.txt");
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter fdg = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, true));
        fdg.write("" + this.weight);
        fdg.close();

        OutputStreamWriter asdf = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, true));
        asdf.write("" + this.height);
        asdf.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyList.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: yes, i do not know what to do

Comment: so first of all is your file in your location and do you added permission to read it in your manifest  ??

Comment: debug you app and find out what is happening

Comment: C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstApp\app\src\main\assets\bmiwerte.txt

Comment: i am not understanding why you are calling Environment.getDataDirectory() buy keeping file in assets

Comment: I debuged the app, but it still does not work
yes the file is in the path i posted aboth

Comment: Now... you pretend to **write** into the `assets` folder?!

Comment: the getdatadirectory() is to get the path.
i can be wrong, please correct me if so

Comment: getdatadirectory()  always return a external path and your file is inside your project right (inside asset folder)

Comment: yes, but i am not using the emulator
i execute the app on my mobile phone

Comment: look this man http://stackoverflow.com/a/5771369

Comment: and @FrankN.Stein said about writing, check that

Answer (score 0):

Add permissions to AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Edt: Also use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead `Environment.getDataDirectory()` its ReadOnly .

Comment: `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not needed, because it's implicit with `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: See edited answer. {Environment.getDataDirectory()} is read only.

Comment: Look he is keeping file inside assets folder

Comment: ... which **can't be written to**.

Comment: @linuxman Yes (as FrankN.Stein noted), it (asset folder) is read-only.

Comment: @VitaliyA dear you cant write a file in asset folder

Comment: can i use getExternalStorageDirectory(), for input and output?

Comment: @linuxman please google about how to read a file from asset folder and you cant write to a file in asset folder