# Android Studio: Read in a text file, display in pop-up

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an app that contains a "Tip of the Day" feature. This is essentially a pop-up, activated by a button. It currently has filler text right now, but I am trying to create a way in which a text file (stored in src/main/assets) is read, and an individual line is displayed in the pop-up. How can I do this? These lines in the text file are individualized by the return key. I will find a way to display unique tips each time the button is clicked, but I will get to that part later.

Here is the code for the pop-up itself:

```
public class homeFragmentDialog extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder1.setMessage("Filler text.");
    builder1.setCancelable(true);

    builder1.setPositiveButton(
            "Close",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
    alert11.show();

}
}
```

And just in case, here is the fragment file which holds the button that activates the previous activity:

```
public class homeFragment extends Fragment {

View rootView;

private Button button0;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    button0 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDialog);
    button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), homeFragmentDialog.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


    });

    return rootView;

}

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: edited to make it more clear. But: how can I read in a text file that is stored in assets, and output a single line into the dialog pop-up that I created?

Comment: use assetsmanager to read the text file as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771366/reading-a-simple-text-file)

Comment: thanks I'll research it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getAssets()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getAssets()) if you access to a Context:

```
try {
    InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("textfile.txt");
    builder1.setMessage(convertStreamToString(inputStream));
} catch (IOException e){
    // Log exception
}
```

Where convertStreamToString() came from [Pavel Repin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5445161/5055317):

```
static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```

Or you can read the ammount of bytes you want(in your case one line).

## EDIT:

Instead of convertStreamToString(), you can use this method to get a single line:

```
static String getLineFromStream(java.io.InputStream is, int linePos){
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String line = null;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i <= linePos; i++) {
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        // Handle exception here (or you can throw)
    }

    return line;
}
```

Comment: Looks solid. I am getting the "Cannot resolve method convertStreamToString" error though. It must be the easiest error to fix that my lack of experience is causing.

edit: Got this to work. It displays the entire text file in the dialog pop-up which is a big step. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I added a method to read only one line, please check if this works for you.

Comment: This is an elementary error, but when I write "builder1.setMessage(getLineFromStream(inputStream);" it says (InputStream, int) cannot be applied to it. That makes sense, since getLineFromStream uses (InputStream, int)... but how do I make that first line work? I tried "builder1.setMessage(getLineFromStream(inputStream, linePos);" but that fails.

Comment: Sorry, I did't explained the method. The linePos is the line of the file you want to read, so if you want to test, you can put a line number (for example: 0 will get the first line, 1 the second and so on. Just make sure the line exists, because if not it will throw an IOException.

Comment: So I erased "int linePos" and change the interior code to "for (int i = 0; i <= 13; i++)" since there are 14 total lines in my text file. Maybe I'm hindering myself by doing that, unless it's what you were recommending I do.

Regardless, this solved the bulk of my problems with getting this feature implemented. I'm very grateful, thank you so much.

Comment: Since you probably will track what line you must show on the next startup (or randomly get one), I recommend you use the method to get a line like this:

`int line = getTodayLine(); // It's up to you how you will get it.`

and later call:

...`getLineFromStream(inputStream, line)`...

So you get a code less coupled.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://sree.cc/google/reading-text-file-from-assets-folder-in-android) should be enough for you to fetch the information from the text file in the assets folder as String.

If you have problems with this short code snippet [this one](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-read-file-from-assets/) should be way more extensive.

Once you got the text as a String object you should be able to add it inside your *setMessage* function to display it.

Comment: I'm confident about this method. From your first link, how can I use .setMessage to display what is stored in the String str_data? I tried declaring in the strings.xml "<string name="str_data">homeFragmentDialog</string>" and then changing .setMessage to "builder1.setMessage(R.string.str_data);" but that just made the dialog show "homeFragmentDialog" (I can see why it does that now).

Comment: Revan TB: Even though Alan Wink's response essentially works for me, I would still like to know how to use .setMessage() to display the str_data variable from yours if you have time to explain. Thanks a lot.

Comment: To display the content of str_data in your dialog you just have to put it into your setMessage method as a parameter. The whole line of code should look like this: **builder1.setMessage(str_data)**