# Visual Novel Game What library/size and where to store my text?

Tags: java, android, graphics, storage, libraries

I'd like to create Visual Novel game for android and my questions are:

1. Where should I store my strings(text)
2. What size should background image be so that it could fit different scene sizes and resolutions.
3. What library should I use ? Libgdx ? or maybe other ?

Visual Novel Game Example:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Wikipe-tan_visual_novel_(Ren'Py).png

Thanks for taking your time to help sincerely and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can store text file(s) in an assets folder. See this: 
   [Reading a simple text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771366/reading-a-simple-text-file)
2. Follow this link to cater for various screen sizes. It tells you how to manage image sizes for different screen sizes/layouts etc.
   https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
3. Assuming that a visual novel type game is limited to button clicks for choices and just showing new images based on your choice, you can probably do it even without the libraries. However this question on Gamedev has a bunch of libraries you can further look into.
   https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/89/2d-gaming-libraries-frameworks-engines-for-android

Comment: 4. Use http://tyranobuilder.com/ best multiplatform constructor for VN!

Comment: If you follow @KristoferSanders' solution, you don't even need to worry about #1,2,3.