# Android Pdf Viewer FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, pdfviewer

I am trying to show pdf file in my application. I am using Pdf Viewer library(https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer). I have put a pdf file in my assets folder. But when I try to load the file it shows this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.samsung.secautomation/com.samsung.secautomation.ui.activities.ShowPdfActivity}: com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.exception.FileNotFoundException: src/main/assets/test does not exist
```

Here is my code:

```
com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView pdfView=(com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfViewer);
    pdfView.fromAsset("src/main/assets/test") //test is the pdf file name
            .pages(0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3) // all pages are displayed by default
            .enableSwipe(true)
            .swipeHorizontal(false)
            .enableDoubletap(true)
            .defaultPage(0)
            .enableAnnotationRendering(false)
            .password(null)
            .scrollHandle(null)
            .load();
```

Here is my permission in Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Is there any way to solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post some more details?? For example the Project structure. I think the file path is wrong... maybe try to add ".pdf" to the path...

Comment: Also looks like you shouldn't put this 'src/main/assets/test' path. try: pdfView.fromAsset("test.pdf"). Inside the PDFView.fromAsset 'context.getAssets().open()' is used http://stackoverflow.com/a/5771369/1533933 so you should not write path from your source code folder

Comment: `src/main/assets/test` ?  if file on compile machine is not in `.....assets/src/main/assets/` and is not called `test` without ext. then `FileNotFoundException  is obvious ...

Comment: pdfView.fromAsset() take only String as parameter thats why I put the file location.
The application structure is Project-->app-->src-->main-->assets-->test.pdf

Comment: assets are in a "pre-defined" location, and do not refer to your build path.  same is true for all the Android asset files.

Comment: none of the given permissions are required to read your own files, e.g. assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `src/main/assets/test` with `test`. `src/main/assets/test` is a relative path to this file *on your development machine*, not in the assets as packaged on the device.

Note that I assume that you manually removed the `.pdf` extension from the file when you put it in `src/main/assets/`. If that file still has the `.pdf` extension, you probably need it in your code. Resources drop their extensions; assets do not.