# Specify custom folder address in android app package

Tags: java, android

I want to add a Text file in my android app in package itself so that no one can re-edit or delete it. I am using `BufferedReader` and `FileReader` functions to access it but I am facing problem in giving the path of the file as it shows my laptop path which will change when app is installed on phones. So require some better option to specify the path of file. I have created a folder in `src` of app and using android studio to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your text file in asset folder of android
refer this answer for the example
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5771369/5409229

Example Code

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Android Code

```
 package com.javasamples;

//reading an embedded RAW data file

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.*;

public class FileDemo1 extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
try {
    PlayWithRawFiles();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                 "Problems: " + e.getMessage(), 1).show();
}
  }// onCreate

public void PlayWithRawFiles() throws IOException {      
String str="";
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();          
InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.myfolder.text_file);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
if (is!=null) {                         
    while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
        buf.append(str + "\n" );
    }               
}       
is.close(); 
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
        buf.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              


}// PlayWithSDFiles

} // FilesDemo4
```

Comment: @Chandraman Patil check if this is what you want if yes then accept the answer

Comment: This worked, but just had to change the line "R.drawable.my_base_data" to "R.myfolder.text_file" as drawable folder doesn't store .txt files so i made a new directory in res folder.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks and up vote this answer so other get the benefits