# Reading a file in android

Tags: android

I am writing an android app where I am trying to read from a data base that I added in `assets` folder in `main` folder. But I am get an error `file not found exception`

```
public File database = new File("/assets/GeoIP2.mmdb");
```

PS : It's a database file not a text file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a simple text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771366/reading-a-simple-text-file)

Comment: i think 
public File database = new File("GeoIP2.mmdb"); its enough

Comment: Check this - http://www.androprogrammer.com/2014/08/create-or-copy-database-in-android.html

Comment: @MohammedAtif : This is not a text file!

Comment: It's the same method, though. You can't treat assets like regular files. You have to get an `InputStream` from `AssetManager`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5771381

Comment: @Ashwin with 3,278 points I assumed that you will be able to figure out that reading a file,  text or db, will have same procedure. Next time I will make sure I provide explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way to read files from assets folder

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("GeoIP2.mmdb");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this below code its working 100%

```
private String readFromFile(String name) {

    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(name + ".txt");

        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                stringBuilder.append("\n");
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

just change the format of your file instead of .txt

Answer (score 0):

InputStream is = getAssets().open("thirukkuralxml.xml");

Answer (score -1):

```
 try{
            String verify, putData;
            File file = new File("file.txt");
            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("Some text here for a reason");
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            while( (verify=br.readLine()) != null ){ //***editted
                       //**deleted**verify = br.readLine();**
                if(verify != null){ //***edited
                    putData = verify.replaceAll("here", "there");
                    bw.write(putData);
                }
            }
            br.close();


        }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```