# PDF rendering in android

Tags: android

I am newbie to android and development world. I need help to solve this problem.(scenario as follows)

I have created one android app using HTML5 and CSS and bundle it out using phonegap.
Now I need to display PDF file in this app with two options for user whether ***first download and then read*** or second ***read online***

So My problem is, I am not able to dispaly PDF in app. 
How could I achieve this? please help . I am trying to solve it from last 4 days and tried out each and solution which is already given in forum ,  but still no success.

It would be great for me if someone ans step by step procedure or one example to refer.

Thank You
Minal

Answer (score 0):

This may help: [How to open a PDF via Intent from SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530416/how-to-open-a-pdf-via-intent-from-sd-card)

The basic idea is to get a pdf app to render the pdf for you, and your app just kicks off an intent to do that.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
private void openBook() {
    File file = new File(mRealPath);
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setDataAndType(path, getString(R.string.application_type));
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(FirstTab.this, 
                getString(R.string.no_application_found), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can open pdf file via intent like this

`File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/example.pdf");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),”application/pdf”);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);`