# how to check for file duplicate before downloading it with Uri.parse

Tags: java, android, uri

My app has a link to open a pdf using:

```
Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://linkgoeshere/filename.pdf")
```

this works fine when the user wants to see the pdf the first time. however i dont want the user to download the file over and over again when it is already available on the device. So, how do I check if the file already exists (afaik the download path depends on the used device/ android version), and in case it exists how do i open it directly instead of downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has a default download directory:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

You can check this directory for the downloaded file (API >= 8)

Opening a pdf file is described here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530416](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530416/how-to-open-a-pdf-via-intent-from-sd-card)

Comment: thanks, i ll try this later today. any more hints about how to check for the existing pdf file before opening?

Comment: File f = new File(filePathString);
if(f.exists())