# How to open a PDF file onclick of a button in Android?

Tags: android, pdf

I need to save PDF file when my app installs and then open it when a user clicks on a button. I found many solutions but was not able to integrate them into one.

Comment: You need to add some more detail then.
What solutions were you not able to integrate?
Did you try using intents?

Comment: I found in one of the answers that I have to keep the pdf file in res/raw folder during compile time and then it will get into the device during installation. After that I can use it using Resources.openRawResource() with the resource ID, which is R.raw.filename. But it is not working for me.

Comment: No, I haven't tried using intents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, display pdf file from a file location (works from any file location, not SDcard specific)

[How to open a PDF via Intent from SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530416/how-to-open-a-pdf-via-intent-from-sd-card)

Comment: But before this my file should be in the device. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: It's not working with asset or raw folder but when I copy the file manually in the internal memory it works.

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085574/read-a-pdf-file-from-assets-folder

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this in work today and it is not that easy.

1) saving the file is not difficult any normal file code will work for a pdf file.

2) showing the pdf you have two options you can display a pdf in a webview if the device has internet access by displaying a Webview and loading google docs with you pdf file at the end of the url

3) or you can create an intent and see if the device has an application that will display the file, you will need to use a FileProvider to get it to run but there is a good post

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Comment: Pease tell me how to save the file first.

Comment: Where are you getting it from, the Web? Or are you shipping it with the app

Comment: Shipping it with the app.

Comment: Drop it in the asset folder of your project