# How to display a PDF from a uri)?

Tags: java, android

I have a uri for a PDF file (which I am storing on Firebase Storage) and I am trying to display it on the screen to the user. I have found a bunch of people talking about the PDF Renderer found in API 21 and later but the answers I have found seem outdated and don't work. Here is my code so far

```
//Get image from database
StorageReference pdfRef = storageReference.child(userID + "/reports/" + reportID);
pdfRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

    }
});
```

What is the simplest way to take the uri I already have and display the PDF which it leads to?

Comment: What about use a WebView to display the PDF?

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't seem to load

Comment: A webview cannot display a pdf file to begin with.

Comment: If you downloaded the file you can use ACTION_VIEW to let the user choose a pdf viewer.

Comment: loading it in a pdf viewer is a option if I cant find a way for it to load in app but I would prefer it to be displayed directly in the app if possible

Comment: return it as a Stream, and update the response headers. setHeader("content-type","application/pdf")

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1- If you want to open PDF in your app, you can use this library: https://github.com/viavansi/mupdf-android

2- You can open it in a PDF viewer, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10530506/6603416